# Can not create multiple text area after deleting using Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need some help. I am creating multiple texareas using `+` button and deleting using `-` button but I am running into some issues.

This is my code:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="ques">No of questions</label>
      <input name="no_of_question" id="ques" class="form-control" placeholder="no of question" value="" type="text">


      <div id="err_msg_name" style="font-size:12px; color:#FF0000; text-align: center;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Questions</label>
        <input type="button" style="line-height:13px; margin-right:2px;" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" name="plus" id="plus" value="+" onClick="addQuestionField();">
        <input type="button" style="line-height:13px; margin-right:2px;" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" name="minus" id="minus" value="-" onClick="deleteQuestionField();">
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div id="container">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="form-control" name="questions0" id="questions0" placeholder="Questions" style="background:#FFFFFF;" rows="2"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    function addQuestionField() {
      var get = $("#ques").val();
      console.log('ques', get);
      for (var i = 1; i < get; i++) {
        $('#container').append('<div class="col-md-4 dyn"><div class="form-group"><textarea class="form-control" name="questions' + i + '" id="questions' + i + '" placeholder="Questions" style="background:#FFFFFF;" rows="2"></textarea></div></div>')
      }
    }

    function deleteQuestionField() {
      var textareas = $('#container .dyn');
      if (textareas.length !== 0) {
        textareas.last().remove();
        $('#ques').val(textareas.length - 1);
      }
    }
  </script>
```

Basically what I need to do is to add new textareas with a unique id, and ordered by this id, to the page according to the number entered in the first textbox. One Default textarea should always be in the page.

So for example if I entered `3` in the textbox, 2 textareas should be added, if I enter `5`- 4 textareas should be added etc.

But the above code is not working properly: For example I entered `2` in the first textbox and clicked on the `+` button- 1 textarea is being created and added to the page (what is good), the same thing in the second time, but on the third time it's not working anymore, an extra textbox is being created.

(For example: I entered the `3` digit, and 3 new textareas are being added + the default one = 4 ,but I only need 3- as entered in the textbox)

My full plunker code [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/xpdHPzN85FNIZ4XNNB1z).

Comment: in your plunker, if you enter 3, only 3 text area are appended. if you enter 2 , another 2, again enter 3, next 3 are appending.

Comment: Yes, that is the problem. The total no of question field should same as entered value in `no of questions` field value.

Comment: In that case, , make the get value `-1` i.e`get = get - 1`.

Comment: I tested in your plunker, if you do `get = get - 1`, then, if you enter 3, then including default 1, it will add 2 more text area.

Comment: Added answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the OP claimed he also needs to keep the id and the name of the textareas serially.

Before adding the new textarea, we remove all the textareas that were added before.

```
function addQuestionField() {
  var get = $("#ques").val();
  var count=$('textarea').length -1 ;
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
   $('#container').find('.col-md-4').last().remove();
  }
  for (var i = 1; i < get; i++) {
   $('#container').append('<div class="col-md-4 dyn"><div class="form-group"><textarea class="form-control" name="questions' + i + '" id="questions' + i + '" placeholder="Questions" style="background:#FFFFFF;" rows="2"></textarea></div></div>')
  }
}
```

I also noticed that it messed up the `deleteQuestionField` function, you should correct it as bellow:

```
function deleteQuestionField() {
  var textareas = $('textarea');
  if (textareas.length !== 0) {
    textareas.last().remove();
    $('#ques').val(textareas.length - 1);
  }
}
```

A working plunker code [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/UeiRgj31ItZQerU4H9bV?p=preview).

Comment: If you are starting from `i=0` the the fiest two text area `name and id ` will same which i dont need.

Comment: I'm not really sure that I understand your issue, can you explain it again?

Comment: My issue is suppose user first entered `2` and created 2 text area including existing one again suppose user entered `3` it is creating `4` where it should create `3` text area including existing one.

Comment: Your problem is that the first time it works properly but then an additional text area is being created each time?

Comment: yes,that true. Suppose user need to create 3 but wrongly created `2` then it should change.

Comment: Yes,in some case its working but while varing like this 2-5-2 it not working. But your updated code is also ok.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127597/discussion-between-satya-and-user3378165).

Answer (score 1):

Make a small change, It will add same text area mention in the input field (including the existing one) .

```
function addQuestionField() {
  var get = $("#ques").val();
  var noOfTextArea = $('textarea').length;

  if(get > noOfTextArea){
    get = get - noOfTextArea;

    for (var i = 1; i <= get; i++) {
      $('#container').append('<div class="col-md-4 dyn"><div class="form-group"><textarea class="form-control" name="questions' + i + '" id="questions' + i + '" placeholder="Questions" style="background:#FFFFFF;" rows="2"></textarea></div></div>')
    }
  }else{
    get = noOfTextArea - get;
    for (var i = 1; i <= get; i++) {
      $('#container').find('.col-md-4').last().remove();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: First entered 2 and create and then entered `3` it should create 3.

Comment: I have updated my answer, please have a look. and please remove all the alerts.

Answer (score 0):

**you are using for loop by starting index at 1 so you should use "<="**

```
 for (var i = 1; i <=get; i++) {
        $('#container').append('<div class="col-md-4 dyn"><div class="form-group"><textarea class="form-control" name="questions' + i + '" id="questions' + i + '" placeholder="Questions" style="background:#FFFFFF;" rows="2"></textarea></div></div>')
      }
```

Comment: No,it will create more that entered value.

Answer (score 0):

- Your Code is perfect.The reason that that more boxes are getting created is because in your code there is already a form-area present,in addition to that one text area the number of text areas you have specified gets created.
- So for example there is already one text area present on load of the screen,when you enter 5 into the text box for creation.5+1 text areas are seen on the screen.
- If you remove the existing text area you will be able to see the exact number of text areas you specified on the screen.
- Furthermore if your change the limit to <=limit then <=5 will be created else else less than 5 that is 4 will be created

Comment: yes,i have already one then i need to create additional. BTW any how i have to create the nos of question field that has entered before. I dont want to remove the existing text area.

Comment: ok when i checked the code on my machine when creating the text boxes ,instead of for example 5 getting added only 4 are getting added,that is because the < condition has been given instead of the <= condition in the for loop .if you try with <=5 then 5 will be created in addition to the one already existing on the page

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code....

```
function addQuestionField() {
  var get = $("#ques").val();
  var textlen = $('textarea').length;

  get = get - textlen;

  //console.log('ques', get);
  for (var i = 0; i < get; i++) {
    $('#container').append('<div class=col-md-4 dyn><div class=form-group><textarea class=form-control name=questions"+i+" id=questions"+i+" placeholder="Questions" style="background:#FFFFFF;" rows="2"></textarea></div></div>')
  }
}

function deleteQuestionField() {
  var textareas = $('textarea');
  if (textareas.length !== 0) {
    textareas.last().remove();
    $('#ques').val(textareas.length - 1);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

make some way to get new id always,

```js
var idGernator = (function (){
     var id = 10;
     return function(){
       return id++;
     }
   })();
    function addQuestionField() {
      var get = $("#ques").val();
     // console.log('ques', get);
    //  var textareas = $('#container .dyn');
     // console.log('text',textareas);
    // var get = $("#ques").val() - 1;
      for (var i = 1; i <= get; i++) {
        var id = idGernator();
        $('#container').append('<div  class="col-md-4 dyn"><div class="form-group"><textarea class="form-control" name="questions' + id + '" id="questions' + id + '" placeholder="Questions" style="background:#FFFFFF;" rows="2"></textarea></div></div>');
        console.log("new id: "+ id);
      }
    }

    function deleteQuestionField() {
      var textareas = $('#container .dyn');
      if (textareas.length !== 0) {
        textareas.last().remove();
        $('#ques').val(textareas.length - 1);
      }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Hello</h1>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="ques">No of questions</label>
      <input name="no_of_question" id="ques" class="form-control" placeholder="no of question" value="" type="text">


      <div id="err_msg_name" style="font-size:12px; color:#FF0000; text-align: center;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Questions</label>
        <input type="button" style="line-height:13px; margin-right:2px;" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" name="plus" id="plus" value="+" onClick="addQuestionField();">
        <input type="button" style="line-height:13px; margin-right:2px;" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" name="minus" id="minus" value="-" onClick="deleteQuestionField();">
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div id="container">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="form-control" name="questions0" id="questions0" placeholder="Questions" style="background:#FFFFFF;" rows="2"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```